# Laravel colecciones array

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo la siguiente función que descuenta los días domingos de un rango de fechas y los días festivos que esten en ese intervarlo funciona bien, el problema se presenta que necesito mostrar los datos en mi vista pero al realizar el `return` sólo me regresa el ultimo valor, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
public function prueba(){

        $fechas = Incidencia::where('tipo_incidencia', 3)->get();
   
          foreach ($fechas as $item) {
        
            $startsAt = $item['fechaAlta'];
            $endsAt =  $item['fechaFin'];
          
             if ($startsAt === null) {
                        $fechainicial = new DateTime(strtotime("today"));
                    } else {
                        $fechainicial = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $startsAt);
                    }
                    if ($endsAt === null) {
                        $fechafinal = new DateTime(strtotime("today"));
                    } else {
                        $fechafinal = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $endsAt);
                    }
                
                    //dias habiles entre 2 fechas
                    $diferenciaendias = $fechafinal->diff($fechainicial);
                       
                   
                    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
                    $daterange = new DatePeriod($fechainicial, $interval ,$fechafinal);
                   
                    //obtengo los feriados de la bdd 
                    $feriados = Calendario::whereBetween('startdate', [$fechainicial->format('Y-m-d'), $fechafinal->format('Y-m-d')])->get();
                       
                
                       
                  $feriados->count();
                   
                   $diasHabiles = 0;
                   
                    //saco los fines de semana y los feriados 
                    foreach($daterange as $date){
                       if ($date->format("N") === '7') {
                        continue;
                       } 
                       $diasHabiles++;
                    }
                   
                    echo $normales = $diferenciaendias->days;
                    echo $descuentos = $diasHabiles - $feriados->count();
                    echo " <hr/>";   
        }
                return view('testeo',compact('normales','descuentos'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer esto estás haciendo dos cosas mal:

```
echo $normales = $diferenciaendias->days;
echo $descuentos = $diasHabiles - $feriados->count();
```

que son imprimir en pantalla algo que seguramente no esperas, y sobreescribir las variables $normales y $descuentos en cada ciclo, de tal forma que el último ciclo es el que realmente estás pasando a la vista al salir del bucle.

Para solucionarlo debes inicializar las variables antes del primer foreach de este modo:

```
$normales = [];
$descuentos = [];
```

y después sustituir las lineas de antes por estas:

```
$normales[] = $diferenciaendias->days;
$descuentos[] = $diasHabiles - $feriados->count();
```

pues de este modo estarás agregando esos valores a las variables (que ahora son del tipo array) sin sobreescribilas y que después podrás recorrer en tu vista correctamente, tratándolas como arrays.

Comment: Me ayudo bastante gracias, solo una duda como puedo recorrer en mi vista ese array

Comment: Con un bucle supongo.  En [este enlace](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops) hay algunos ejemplos